# Facebook FQL returning inconsistent/conflicting results

Tags: facebook-fql

I'm using Facebook's FQL to query:

`Fql.execute({
  "query1" => "select object_id from photo_tag where subject=me()",
  "query2" => "select object_id, subject from photo_tag where object_id in (select object_id from #query1)", 
  options_dict_with_my_access_token)`

query1 gets all photos that have me as a tagged subject
query2 goes to the same table and tries to load those photos with all the subjects

but query 2 fails to load rows for many of the photos that were the result of query1, which is impossible, since i know at least i'm 1 such result.

how does this work?

Comment: You might be bumping up against an internal limit in `query2`. Try adding `LIMIT 1000` to the end of it and see if that helps.

Comment: good guess, but no dice.. that query returns 234 results, so it doesn't feel like a limit issue.